# UrbanAirship is unable to accept arguments

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

Using Android Urban Airship 4.0.2

Logcat displays
`Action com.urbanairship.actions.tags.AddTagsAction@4292b848 is unable to accept arguments: ActionArguments situation: MANUAL_INVOCATION value: ["value1","value2"]`

When I try to send a JSON Array of tag values that urban airship requires

Their tag documentation says `ActionArguments` can take a string or JSON Array of strings.

my code:

`ActionArguments args = new ActionArguments(Situation.MANUAL_INVOCATION, mAdd);
                        ActionRunner.shared().runAction("add_tags_action", args);`

where `mAdd` is a jsonArray. I've also passed mAdd as `mAdd.toString()` which is a string representation of the json array. This does post the tags but as only as one long tag, on UrbanAirship it registers the one string, no parsing done on there end.

Insight appreciated. The real problem is that it is "unable to accept arguments"

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this very same thing. I found that with other tag related functionality they have been using the Set data struct and not so much JSON Arrays as they have documented.

Anyways, here are the goods:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
            set.add( String.format( "sdk_%s", Build.VERSION.SDK_INT ) );
            set.add( String.format( "release_%s", Build.VERSION.RELEASE ) );
            set.add( String.format( "model_%s", Build.MODEL ) );
            set.add( String.format( "manufacturer_%s", Build.MANUFACTURER.replace( " ", "_" ) ) );
            set.add( String.format( "language_%s", context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getISO3Language() ) );
            set.add( String.format( "country_%s", context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getISO3Country() ) );
            ActionRunner.shared().runAction( "add_tags_action", new ActionArguments( Situation.MANUAL_INVOCATION, set ) );
```